# Chaining seperate animations that work on the same properties

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have looked at [Staggered animations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations) for chaining animations but there they use one animation for one widget's properties, e.g. a opacity animation is controlling the fade in, but what if I want to first fade in and then later fade out that same widget? I mean I already have created the fade in animation and that is used for the widget opacity value like this:

```
_opacityDontWorry = Tween(
  begin: 0.0,
  end: 1.0,
).animate(
  CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Interval(0.0, 0.75, curve: Curves.easeIn)),
);
```

so those two are now bound together like this:

```
Opacity(
  opacity: _opacityDontWorry.value,
  child: Text("Don't worry"),
)
```

This work just fine and my Opacity get faded in, but after it is faded in I would like it to fade out after a short pause, but how can I do this? Do I create a new Tween and overwrite the _opacityDontWorry with that, or? Am I even on the right path here, how do I chain multiple animations that alter the same properties on a widget?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: I don't understand your question. Isn't your code working?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to clarify a little.

Comment: @Neigaard hi Neigaard, by any chance, you know how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328866/how-to-tween-animate-a-text-from-opacity-1-to-0-and-back-to-1-with-one-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addStatusListener` on your `Animation`. Check when the animation is completed and then call `reverse()` on your `AnimationController`.

If you want to, you can call `reverse()` inside a `Future.delayed()` for making a pause.

I've made this example for you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _opacityDontWorry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
    _opacityDontWorry = Tween(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn),
    )..addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          _animationController.reverse();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: Text('Animate'),
        onPressed: () => _animationController.forward(),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _opacityDontWorry,
          builder: (context, widget) {
            return Opacity(
              opacity: _opacityDontWorry.value,
              child: Text("Don't worry"),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In case you need to play this animation, and call another one after that, you can extract the opacity value to a variable. Then update that value from as many consecutive animations as you need.

```
  _firstAnimation = Tween(
    begin: 0.0,
    end: 1.0,
  ).animate(
    CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Interval(0.0, 0.20, curve: Curves.easeIn)),
  )..addListener(() {
      setState(() => _opacity = _firstAnimation.value);
    });

  // Leave an interval pause if you need
  _secondAnimation = Tween(
    begin: 1.0,
    end: 0.0,
  ).animate(
    CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Interval(0.40, 0.60, curve: Curves.easeIn)),
  )..addListener(() {
      setState(() => _opacity = _secondAnimation.value);
    });
```

In your widget's opacity property, instead of using `_firstAnimation.value` use `_opacity`.

Comment: And if you then want another animation after that, then what is the best way to go about that? Multiple animation controllers? It seems a bit cumbersome but if that is the way...

Comment: Well, it would be helpful if you explain what you need to do. If you need to fade in, wait, and then fade out, this is the way to go. :) The same may apply for another kind of animations, of course. But maybe you're thinking about something specifically?

Comment: Specificly now I want to fade a text in, then out, then change the text and fade it in again. This can be done with the reverse I can see (had not thought about that), but for bigger combinations it seems something else is needed, I mean what if I wanted to fade out, then in, then move it or totate it? But maybe that is a different question for when I need it :)

Comment: I would like to note that you can control the animation the whole time. You can use `addListener` and check the current value of your animation Tween, do something when value is > than x, forward from ther again, stop, reset, etc.

Comment: I see. I'm thinking about combining staggered animation with my answer. But you'll need a little trick, because of the intervals. As you'll need a pause you should leave an empty space on your intervals. You know what I mean? If your first animation's interval is 0.0 to 0.2, the next can use 0.5 to 1.0, leaving a pause from 0.2 to 0.5 where the reverse can be called. You just need to orchestrate the animation times well.

Comment: Yes I understand :) But then if I want to fade in then out and I use reverse, but after that I want to do some other animations, would you still use staggered animations and then just forward to some specific point to start other steps?

Comment: @Neigaard You're right about forwarding the controller. I've updated my answer with another solution. :)

Comment: It is not working, if I comment out the _secodAnimation my Opacity fades in just fine, but if the _secondAnimation is not commented out my Opacity starts with 1.0 and the _firstAnimation has no effect. It is as if the _secondAnimation's start value is applied immediately even though the animation will start much later, maybe I need to construct this of multiple animation controllers?

Comment: I'll test it today later and see if I can make it work. We want to avoid multiple controllers.. There must be a better way. xD

Comment: @GaboBrandX Hi gabo! by any chance you knw how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328866/how-to-tween-animate-a-text-from-opacity-1-to-0-and-back-to-1-with-one-button

Answer (score 6):

May be this is a late answer. But a TweenSequence is the right class for animating the same attribute(s) mutations one after another. [Docs reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html).