# Flutter staggered animation on same property

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, flutter-animation

I want to animate the scale of a widget.
On tap down it should scale down and on tap up, scale up.

Problem is how can I use [staggered animations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations) on the same property?
There is an older question here on SO ([Chaining seperate animations that work on the same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901101/chaining-seperate-animations-that-work-on-the-same-properties)) but it has no working answers.

Ive tried to adapt its solution but the problem is each animation listener is called even if the specified `Interval` has not been reached.

Ive added a condition which checks if `_animationFuture` is set but with this pattern you have to keep a value for any running animation you have in your widget which is a bit cumbersome.

Is there a "native" solution where you dont need a work around or are multiple animations on same value just not supported?

I do not want to `reverse()` the animation. Each tween must be able to have a custom curve, begin and end values.

Heres my widget:

```
class AnimatedIconButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget child;

  final Function onPress;

  AnimatedIconButton({@required this.child, this.onPress}): assert(child != null);

  @override
  _AnimatedIconButtonState createState() => _AnimatedIconButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedIconButtonState extends State<AnimatedIconButton> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  Animation<double> _animationIn;
  Animation<double> _animationOut;

  double _scale = 1;

  TickerFuture _animationFuture;


  Function get onPress => widget.onPress ?? () => null;

  _tapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    print("_tapDown progress=${_animationController.value} scale=$_scale");
    _animationFuture = _animationController.animateTo(0.5);
  }

  _tapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    assert(_animationFuture != null);
    print("_tapUp progress=${_animationController.value} scale=$_scale");

    _animationFuture.then((_) {
      _animationFuture = null;
      _animationController.animateTo(1);
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController = AnimationController(value: 0, vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), animationBehavior: AnimationBehavior.preserve);

    _animationIn = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.9).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeOut,
      ),
    ))..addListener(() {
      if (_animationFuture == null) return;
      print("_animationIn.value ${_animationOut.value}");
      _scale = _animationIn.value;
    });

    _animationOut = Tween<double>(begin: 0.9, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
          0.5, 1, curve: Curves.elasticOut,
      ),
    ))..addListener(() {
      if (_animationFuture != null) return;
      print("_animationOut.value ${_animationOut.value}");
       _scale = _animationOut.value;
    });



  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onTapUp: _tapUp,
      onTapDown: _tapDown,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        child: widget.child,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return Transform.scale(
            scale: _scale,
            transformHitTests: false,
            child: child,
          );
        },
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve it? intervall fires from beginning even if I define it from 0.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TweenSequence](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html) to stagger multiple animations behind each other. Borrowing the example from the documentation and changing it a bit, here's a copy-paste widget that animates a blue container from 100x100 to 200x200, pauses for a bit, and animates it back:

```dart
class _StaggeredState extends State<Staggered>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  /// Controller managing the animation
  late final AnimationController controller;

  /// The aninmation of our TweenSequence
  late final Animation<double> animation;

  /// An Animatable consisting of a series of tweens
  final Animatable<double> tweenSequence = TweenSequence<double>(
    <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
      // Animate from .5 to 1 in the first 40/80th of this animation
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 100, end: 200)
            .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
        weight: 40.0,
      ),
      // Maintain still at 1.0 for 20/80th
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        tween: ConstantTween<double>(200),
        weight: 20.0,
      ),
      // Animate back from 1 to 0.5 for the last 40/80th
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 200, end: 100)
            .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
        weight: 40.0,
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );

    // Animate our TweenSequence using our controller
    animation = tweenSequence.animate(controller);

    // Add a listener that calls [setState] so our widget rebuilds
    // when the animation value changes.
    controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    // Set the controller to repeat indefinitely
    controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: animation.value,
            height: animation.value,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a listener that calls `setState` every time the controller value is changed, it's better to user the Flutter class `AnimatedBuilder`, passing the animation as a parameter.